# swf accessed by HTTP protocol makes java execute sun.net.httpserver.StreamClosedException

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I have an swf file that is accessing the server by sockets, but at the same time this server is an HTTP server, so when I make url request:

```
http://localhost/flash/my.swf
```

java generates this error:

```
sun.net.httpserver.StreamClosedException
```

BUT if I make this request:

```
file:///E:/projects/myProject/flash/my.swf
```

all works fine, why that happens only when I access the swf via HTTP?, maybe there some configuration for this?, any ideas? or maybe its not enough memory to handle those sockets?

Comment: have you set the content-type to be  application/x-shockwave-flash?